# Brace indexing not supported for variable of this type error

Tags: matlab, networking, expansion

I am running a display code for Matlab network expansion problem.
This problem Variables are initialized as:

```
Coll=null(1);v=null(1);
```

The section with the error:

```
nco=size(Coll,1);
oc = Coll {nco,1};
```

oc line gives the brace indexing error.

I tried changing braces to parentheses,the error changed to index in position 2exceeds array bound.
Coll is a 1×0 double while nco is a 1×1 double on my workspace.

I also tried with

```
oc = [Coll{nco,1}];
```

This terminates the problem but does not a sign to display.

Comment: `Coll` is not a cell, so you can't index it with curly braces and need round brackets, it's also got no columns as you've shown, so you can't index into column 1. What are you expecting these statements to return?

Comment: Please format your code block(s), logs and errors, in order to make your question more readable, and receive better quality answers. For more information, take a look on this link: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Please read [mre]. We don’t know what you’re trying to accomplish with these statements, we don’t know how the variables are declared (what is `null`?), we don’t know anything at all, really. Feel free to [edit] your post with a [mre] and clarify the problem.